# eyes not moving 100% with head / eyes lagging behind

Tags: rigging, constraints, weight-painting

I've checked many other same questions.
but none of them helped. It is still not working at my object.
I hope that someone can take a look at it and help me out.

Problem is that the eyes are lagging behind when I move the head.
All other objects do.

- I tried it as separate and connected objects.
- My weight paint seems to be correct.
- I also tried a constraint: child of
- Eye bones are connected to the head.

but still its moving slower then the head.

LINK unlinked. Problem solved.

Comment: Hey I'm no expert at all at rigging but you probably should parent eyes directly to head bone, i cleared parent of eyes then selected eyes and then head bone and then ctrl+p and just choose Bone and eyes are going with head without playing around.

Comment: Another way of fixing it, is to move the eyes just slightly back into the head, as they are already penetrating the surrounding skin at frame 0, a slight difference in movement then causes the eyes to break through further

Comment: @Black Cloud: But they r allready connected to the spine4 which is the head. 1 bone for each eye and either of them r parented to spine 4

Comment: @ WhatAMesh: i also tried to move them further in so that they r not touching any other parts. it also does not work. they always fall behind when i move the head.

Comment: I told you, I cleared parent of eyes, then parented it directly to head bone without weights just to the bone and eyes were moving fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took a look at your file. Rigging eyes is complicated. I think the problem had to do with either:

The eye bones not sitting directly on the origin of the eyeballs...

OR

..that the head bone (spine.004) Y axis didn't sit on the same location as the origin of the eye balls but I'm not sure which or if any of those were what were causing the eyes to yaw off target. It always gets really complicated when you're working with many different bone rotations and origin points etc.

OR

That the eyes were a single object and needed separating. As the front of the head moved from side to side, the eyes only moved in accordance with the rotation of the head bone tail and not at the same height and angle as the eye sockets.

Now, I think it works perfectly but you let me know if it doesn't work.

If you want to follow a good tutorial on it, I use a similar method to this guy. This video is great :)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-9GDj8_bx6M

Here you can download your edited rig:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/5xbykg8brg5msn2/human_male_EDIT.blend?dl=0

Let me know if you can download that file and I'll upload it to another sharing website.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Awesome Mark! Thank you very much. It works now. I'll follow that turorial from now on. Thank you for ur time and help.

Comment: I'm glad it helped and good luck with your project :)